# how do I hide email information in a .net application

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am creating a free program that has a support request page. This will send me an email and a log file so I can see what is going on.

I have created the email class, but like any email program/class it will require a username, password, email address, etc.

Now, once I put this out, I know that, with the right programs, you can view the code behind on .Net, which I really thing is completely absurd.

Anyhow, I don't want this information out there because it's a support email address and is sensitive information.

What is the best way for me to send an email but not include my sensitive information for all the nosy people out there or hide it so they cannot get to it?

Here is an example of the code I'm referring to:

```
 var emailSettings = new EmailSettings();
  emailSettings.Body = richTextBox_Message.Text;
  emailSettings.BodyIsHtml = false;
  emailSettings.EmailServerEnableSsl = true;
  emailSettings.EmailServerPassword = "";
  emailSettings.EmailServerPort = 25;
  emailSettings.EmailServerUsername = "";
  emailSettings.EmailSmtpServer = "";
  emailSettings.FromEmailAddress = new MailAddress(textBox_EmailAddress.Text);
  emailSettings.Subject = comboBox_TypeOfRequest.Text;
```

Scary stuff in there :D

Just to clarify, this is a free app so I cannot afford a program to hide the code. :(

Comment: in fact hiding the code/prevent decompiling the code is a **must-do** for many other security requirements, not just things related to password.

Comment: ok granted, but what do people do to prevent people grabbing the sensitive information?

Comment: I've never done such a thing but I've heard that there are some tools doing that for you. However it does not really ensure that the code can't be decompiled depending on how powerful the tool you use. Another option is you can save the sensitive information on your server, the client will need authorization info manged by server to access/load that sensitive info. That way the information can only be cracked if they attack at your server.

Comment: You just need to encrypt the data in the `app.config`. Here is the best blog I've ever found. http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx There are two ways in there, it's up to you which way you go.

Comment: Duplicate!?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140338/how-can-we-hide-invisible-some-codebehind-lines-for-example-a-class-from-oth

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Good link! I'll give it a shot. Can you supply that as an answer so I can vote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not safe to use this method to send error reports. Consider using a .php file on a web server to send yourself errors, or some other method.

[PHP Email Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp)

But if you really want to, I believe you might be able to use `System.Security.Cryptography` to protect your data, I'm not 100% sure on that though, so correct me if I'm wrong.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That's a very good point. I'll create a web service and just publish the information to it. Think outside of the box!